# MySQL doesn't start on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to log in into a MySQL server using phpMyAdmin, and when I try to start the MySQL Server on XAMPP, it doesn't work. I'm using Xampp 5.6.30

I have already tried to alter the port in my.ini, and also have deleted a few folders because of answers I found on StackOverflow

This is what happens when I try to start it:

```
  [mysql]   Problem detected!
  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I want to log in into phpMyAdmin, but I have only been able to start the Apache server on Xampp.

Comment: what is your OS ?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit @elporfirio

Comment: Something else is using port 3306. It is probably another MySQL server instance that you  tried to install before finding XAMPP

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried closing XAMPP completely, Right clicking it and running it as administrator?

Comment: I do not understand, how do I run as administrator? I closed it and wasn't able to do that.

Comment: Find your "XAMPP Control Panel" icon that opens the XAMPP control panel, right click on that icon, and you should see the option that says "Run as Administrator"